# Align ImageButton right inside Tablerow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton, androiddesignsupport, android-layout-editor

[image]

I want my imagebutton to be aligned right but as you can see its left aligned even when the `gravity="right"`. This is my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 >

<TableRow android:layout_height="20dp">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:graviy="right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

How can I align my imagebutton right? I though gravity="right" would solve the problem? I tryied layout_gravity and gravity. Both dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have `graviy` instead of `gravity`.
`gravity` attribute specifies "how are my children aligned inside of me" - eg. text inside TextView, Views inside Layout.
`layout_gravity` tells parent "how I want to be positioned".
Not all layouts pay respect to `layout_gravity` of their children, in this case setting `gravity="end"` to your `TableRow` works.
You can remove both `gravity` and `layout_gravity` from `ImageButton`.